# How to install FTGL on AWS Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

I have an EC2 instance running so I can compile some c++ programs to run on lambda.  I am trying to build opencascade on my EC2 instance and am running into the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FTGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/ec2-user/oce/adm/cmake/TKOpenGl
FTGL_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "TKOpenGl" in directory /home/ec2-user/oce/adm/cmake/TKOpenGl
```

I fixed similar errors by installing the required library, but I can't seem to find a yum package for FTGL.  I've tried the following:

```
sudo yum install ftgl
sudo yum install ftgl-dev
sudo yum install ftgl-devel
sudo yum install libftgl-dev
```

I've also searched with no success:

```
yum search *ftgl*
```

Where can I find this library to install it on my EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). To enable it and install on [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/):

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel

sudo yum install ftgl-devel
```